# Prioritizing sub-searches, returning results in a reasonable time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a query in SQL that performs a real-time text search. We've enabled trigram indexes to help speed up the search (We're using Postgres, but I think some of this question is a general SQL problem).

What I'd like is a prioritized list of results

1. textcol ILIKE 'age%', shortest first  (Typically few matches, sorting is fast)
2. textcol ILIKE '% age%', shortest first (Typically few matches, sorting is fast)
3. textcol ILIKE '%age%', shortest first   (Very many matches, but we likely don't care strongly for short matches).

... results should be ordered by priority, with subsequent duplicates excluded,
(and where 'age' is the query string).

We could try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE 'age%' ORDER BY LENGTH(textcol) ) a
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE '% age%' ORDER BY LENGTH(textcol) ) a
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE '%age%' ORDER BY LENGTH(textcol) ) c
) z
LIMIT 200
```

But:

- It seems that 3 is grossly expensive (15s if run by itself) for short queries - too many results makes sorting slow. I'd accept unordered result for 3. Not ordering 3 by length reduces the query time to milliseconds.
- SQL doesn't guarantee the priority ordering hoped for

To resolve the ordering issues, we can try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT 1 as priority, textcol FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE 'age%' ) a
  UNION
  (SELECT 2 as priority, textcol FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE 'age%' ) b
  UNION
  (SELECT 3 as priority, textcol FROM TABLE WHERE textcol ILIKE 'age%' ) c
) as t
ORDER BY priority, LENGTH(textcol)
LIMIT 200
```

But again, this is also grossly slow (> 14 seconds) because we're again sorting the large set of matches produced by 3.

We can have the client independently execute each of:

1. textcol ILIKE 'age%'... ORDER BY LENGTH(textcol) ... LIMIT 200 # shortest first
2. textcol ILIKE '% age%'...  ORDER BY LENGTH(textcol) ...LIMIT 200 #  shortest first
3. textcol ILIKE '%age%' ... LIMIT 200 #(unsorted)

... and the result are received in milliseconds (duplicates resolved on the client).
Is there no way to implement this is efficiently in SQL?

Comment: Usually for this problem you would do some form of *full text searching*.  See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-intro.html

Comment: It's not obvious that solves the problem - they describe how to aggregate text sources, which is not my problem.

Comment: What are you doing with the results? Display them?

Comment: Yes. Is a real-time character-at-a-time interactive text search.
The full problem is more complex - sometimes the search has constraints that can't easily be solved in SQL (some minor filtering in client). An ideal solution with literally be:
concat(query 1, query 2, query 3), where 1 and 2 are sorted and 3 is not, and the whole query can be streamed without a final LIMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would start with:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE textcol ILIKE '%age%'
ORDER BY (textcol ILIKE '% age%') DESC,
         (textcol ILIKE 'age%') DESC,
         LENGTH(textcol)
```

This might get around some of the performance bottleneck, such as the duplicate elimination.

If that is not good enough, then based on the last query, you can do:

```
(select t.*
 from table t
 where textcol ilike 'age%'
 order by length(textcol) desc
 limit 200
) union all
(select t.*
 from table t
 where textcol ilike '% age%'
 order by length(textcol) desc
 limit 200
)
union all
(select t.*
 from table t
 where textcol ilike '%age%' and
       not textcol ilike '% age%' and
       not textcol ilike 'age%'
 limit 200
);
```

Comment: Yeah -- maybe a good way. Need a final LIMIT 200 and a final ORDER BY to get the desired results, but not likely big costs.

Comment: Is a good solution ... except.... in one particular use case I have to not to provide a limit to the search (the client performs some small amount of post-filtering that's crazy difficult in SQL -- and the query is limited with the client cursor). I'll repost as another question since I had limits in the OP.

Comment: @user48956 . . . This addresses the question you ask here.  The first query should be faster than your `union` (but probably not fast enough).  The second is based on the solution you included in the question, limiting the results from each subquery.